# At angles you’d have to be careful walking (at)

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses, ellipses

A car review article titled "[Escape the City and the Roads with the 2020 Subaru Outback](https://www.themanual.com/auto/2020-subaru-outback-hands-on-review/)" has this paragraph:

> X-Mode also enables the Hill Descent Control. After a quick coffee break 800 feet above the surf, we headed down a wicked steep dirt track. **At angles [you’d have to be careful walking], the car drove itself.** Hill Descent Control automatically brakes and detects wheel slippage, and adjusts accordingly. I had to hit the gas at times as it was so controlled.

In the emboldened sentence, I think the bracketed relative clause should have the preposition *at* in theory, but adding one would make it not as natural (to my ear) in reality:

> (1) ??At angles you’d have to be careful walking **at**, the car drove itself.
>
> (2) ??At angles **at** which you’d have to be careful walking, the car drove itself.

Is there anyone who'd find (1) and (2) as natural as or more natural than the original?

If not, why is it better to omit **at** in the relative clause when it is grammatically required?

Comment: I much prefer 2. Often accused of being old-fashioned, I do not like clauses that end in prepositions and, I suspect, neither do you. But in this instance, wouldn't it work without any "at". Do we always walk "at an angle". Or can we simply "walk angles"?

Comment: @WS2 It's not so much the preposition stranding as the preposition repeating that bothers me. But the latter doesn't seem to bother you. You prefer 2 to the others. What do you think of the original compared to 1? Also, regarding preposition stranding, though, you wouldn't dislike examples like _Where are you from?_ or _What are you looking at?_, would you?

Comment: @WS2 As for the untenable _walk angles_, the equally untenable _I live the place_ doesn't prevent you from saying _the place I live_.

Comment: However, *In the house I live in* is fine, but **In the house I live* sounds off.

Comment: @Greybeard Does the original text sound off to you?

Comment: Yes - The original sounds "off" to me: "walking angles" is not really idiomatic. **1**. is OK, but **2**. sounds best. Although some might say it is formal, I like it best as what we have is {At angles [*at which you’d have to be careful walking*]} = 1st adverbial + *adjectival modifying angles*. And the whole seems to be a free modifier.

Comment: @JK2 *Where are you from?* and *What are you looking at?*, are acceptable idioms. Many idiomatic expressions are not strictly grammatical (indeed I think that is largely how the word "idiom" is defined). So I've no problems with those, any more than I would have with *Good morning* - a sentence without a verb.

Comment: @Greybeard By saying it "sounds off" (a bit like "the fish smells off") does not address the issue. A site such as this does call for some grasp of the cause of "off".

Comment: @WS2 Are they really idioms? Do you know of any dictionary or grammar that classifies them as idioms? Who gets to decide whether an expression is an idiom or not? Are these all idioms too? _What are you looking for?_ _What were you looking for?_ _What have you been looking for?_ _Who are/were you looking after?_ _Who are/were you coming for/after?_

Comment: @JK2 OED Sense 2A of "idiom" - *A language, especially a person or people's own language; the distinctive form of speech of a particular people or country.* They are certainly "part of a distinctive form of speech".

Comment: @WS2 What are you saying??

Comment: @WS2 The issue is addressed in the explanation of my choice. There is nothing wrong in using a preposition to end a sentence with, but in *"At angles you’d have to be careful walking at,"* the first "at" has reduced emphasis and the second increased. and that sounds strange. However, "At angles at which...", both ats have reduced emphasis and this seems give the expected cadence.

Comment: @Greybeard What do you mean the first "at" has reduced emphasis and the second increased?

Comment: emphasis - the increased stress placed upon a spoken word.

Comment: @Greybeard Got it. But I don't think the different stresses sound "strange". Like you've observed, a preposition is normally not stressed in its canonical position (i.e., before its complement, e.g., _at angles_ and _at which_), but it's stressed when stranded, e.g., _...walking at, ..._. Similarly, an auxiliary is normally not stressed before the remaining part of the predicate, but it is stressed when stranded. Just because you stress a stranded preposition doesn't mean the stranded preposition is ill-formed. E.g. _What are you looking at?_ _I'm looking at you._